# JavaFX how can I reset the application?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

my code opens another window but the first one is still open. How can I close the first window?

```
        ButtonType continue = new ButtonType("Continue");
        ButtonType exit= new ButtonType("Exit");
        alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(continue, exit);
        Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
        if (result .get() == continue ) {
            Controllerxx = new commandCenter();
            centerFX newFX= new centerFX ();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            newFX.start(stage);
        } else if (result .get() == exit) {
            Platform.exit();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try something like below :**

```
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        ((Node) (event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();
    });
```

You can get the current scene by the `Action event` of your exit button and close it.

Comment: Or just `btn.getScene().getWindow().hide()`, since you know `btn` is the source of the event.